# list of items or menu in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

i am creating a database for an android tourism app. 
i am working on MySQL workbench, i want to create a menu in my database, 
for example i want to list the cities of my country, or list the branches of any place around the country.
i read about ENUM & SET datatypes here, and how they are evil to my database 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

what do you all think, what datatype do i need to represent a menu in my database?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a menu. What exactly are you planning on storing? and what do you mean by branches?

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection of primitive types appropriate to the type stored in the database. If you have more than one column from a table then use a collection of a class that you define that will hold all of the primitive types as properties of that class--if appropriate.  Bind your menu UI to the class/collection.